# global variable not passing, saying its not recognized?

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables

I have created a game. It worked perfectly so i thought i would add a screen to change the colour of the 'bullet'. i made the window i assigned the variables i globaled those variables i needed to, however i keep getting a error saying the variable is not been defined, but the other variables underneath that variable that was defined and came from the same 'shop' function were defined. and if i get rid of the normal and have just the FireGun and LaserGun FireGun is not defined. Its hard to explain. so look at the code, which I've dummied down a lot, and see if you can pick out any errors.

```
from tkinter import *

def MainMenu():
    self = Tk()

    self.btnShops = Button(text ="Shop")
    self.btnShops.pack()

    def startShops(event):
        self.destroy()
        Shop()


    self.btnShops.bind('<Button>',startShops)



    self.geometry("830x700")
    self.title("Space Assault")
    self.configure(bg="black")



def Shop():
    self = Tk()


    normal = 1
    fire = 0
    laser = 0

    def FireGun(event):
        global fire
        global normal
        global laser
        fire = 1
        normal = 0
        laser = 0

    def LaserGun(event):
        global laser
        global fire
        global normal
        laser = 1
        fire = 0
        normal = 0


    self.btnfireGun = Button(text="Fire Gun")
    self.btnfireGun.pack()
    self.btnlaser = Button(text = "Laser Gun")
    self.btnlaser.pack()
    self.btnMainMenu = Button(text="Main Menu")
    self.btnMainMenu.pack()


#Bind
    self.btnfireGun.bind('<Button>',FireGun)
    self.btnlaser.bind('<Button>', LaserGun)
    self.btnMainMenu.bind('<Button>',StartMainMenu)

#Frame settings
    self.geometry("830x700")
    self.title("Space Assault Shop")
    self.configure(bg="black")

def singleplayergame():

    def Shoot(event):
        global normal
        global fire
        global laser

        self.shot = Canvas(bg="black",highlightthickness=0,width=10,height=10)
        self.shot.place(x=shotXpos,y=shotYpos)

        if normal == 1:
            self.shot.create_oval(0,0,10,10,fill=random.choice(COLORS))
        elif fire == 1:
            self.shot.create_oval(0,0,10,10,fill='red')
        elif laser == 1:
            self.shot.create_oval(0,0,10,10,fill='blue')

MainMenu()
```

If i clicked on the FireGun button the bullets work fine and they come out red like normal. However if i want it 'normal' it doesn't even fire anything. hope this makes sense. I think its something to do with the global deceleration but im really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Lot's of stuff going on.

You shouldn't be nesting functions like this. If you're trying to encapsulate data / structure it then just use a class. You seem to be wanting to use one by naming `Tk()` self and calling self all over the place. Which is really just setting a bunch of attributes to Tk.

You're creating multiple instances of `Tk()`. If you want new windows then use the `Toplevel()` widget. Otherwise, just use `pack_forget` / `grid_forget` to essentially hide the frame / widget you want and "unhide" the others using pack / grid to replace them on the grid.

No need to have multiple Tk() instances running around.

You never call `mainloop`.

You're calling `global` on your variables which is unnecessary you can restructure. If you're using globals 9/10 you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). They're really not even global to begin with. They're local to the function(s) you have nested.
You can use `nonlocal` if you *really* want this structure. Again, if you're going for a structure like this just use a class and keep these as attributes.

There's no need to use `bind` on all of your buttons just to call a function on click. This is what the `command` argument is for.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a global variable inside a function simply tells that function to use the specified `global` variable of the same name. It does not assign a variable in itself. If you are using Python3 you can use the declaration `nonlocal` instead of `global` inside the embedded functions in the `shop` function to tell the embedded functions to use the functions local to `shop`.

I see that you are want to use the variables in the `singleplayergame` function so consider defining these variables outside of all functions and then importing them through the `global` declaration.

In this case, moving the `normal`, `fire` and `laser` variables outside the `shop` function should do the trick.

Here are some links to help with scope in Python.

[Python scoping: understanding LEGB](https://www.embrangler.com/2011/01/python-scoping-understading-legb/)

[Setting a global variable in a function](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-you-set-a-global-variable-in-a-function.htm)